# Как узнать путь к внешней SD карте памяти?

Tags: android

Тема не новая. Облазил множество сайтов. Но все примеры дают результаты на внутреннюю память. Никак не могу решить вопрос с **определением пути к внешней SD карте**. Мне нужен результат типа **/storage/external_SD**. Именно тут я хочу создать папку и скопировать в нее файл. Телефон LgD380 на 4 андроиде с root. основу приведенного ниже кода я взял с данного сайта. результат, возвращаемый программой - путь к firmware. Для простоты я вставил его в MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView textInfo;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String EXTERNAL_PATH = getSDcardPath() + "/";
    String EXTERNAL_PATH_REPLACE = EXTERNAL_PATH.replace("/mnt/media_rw", "/storage");
}

//Функция определяет путь до внешней извлекаемой карты
private String getSDcardPath() {
    String exts = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();///storage/emulated/0
    String sdCardPath = null;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("/proc/mounts"));
        //FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("/mnt/sdcard"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("secure") || line.contains("asec"))
                continue;
            if (line.contains("fat")) {
                String[] pars = line.split("\\s");
                if (pars.length < 2)
                    continue;
                if (pars[1].equals(exts))
                    continue;
                sdCardPath = pars[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        fr.close();
        br.close();
        return sdCardPath;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        textInfo.setText(e.toString());
    }
    return sdCardPath;
}
```

(см фото)
[image: результат, возвращаемый программой - путь к firmware]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Ну так вроде бы `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` и указывает на SD-карту.
Единственно, если устройство к компу подключили, то SD-карта не доступна для программы. Т.е. получить путь к SD-карте:

```
private String getSDcardPath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
}
```

Смотрите докуметнтацию [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

Проверить возможность работы с SD-картой можно как [здесь описано](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage):

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал еще раз. Мой смарт LG D380 подключен через USB к Пк в режиме зарядки. Для проверки доступности памяти использовал след. код.  
        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable())  {  Toast.makeText(this, "NO external storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   } else {  Toast.makeText(this, "YES external storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        }
        if (isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {             Toast.makeText(this, "NO StorageReadOnly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  } else {     Toast.makeText(this, "YES StorageReadOnly", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    }. Оба раза положит результат.

Comment: Все-таки для меня неясен смысл слов, что "карта памяти недоступна при подкл к ПК". Я же не выбираю опция использоваить как USb накопитель.

Comment: @serjufa, так наверное доступна будет. Накидайте тестовую программку и запишите что-нить в файл на SD. Попробуйте с разными опциями подключения, посмотрите что на SD карте происходит. В манифест еще нужно права на запись/чтение добавить.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой - правда в немного иной трактовке: была необходимость определить подключена ли карта памяти, весь интернет завален бесполезным кодом, для себя нашел решение довольно простое - путь там также есть

```
String s = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    if(s == null)
        Log.d("test", "sdcard not available");
    else
        Log.d("test", System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"));
```