# removable память(внешняя SD), получить путь

Tags: android, android-sdk

**Внутренняя** (**internal**) память — это часть встроенной в телефон карты памяти. При ее использовании по умолчанию папка приложения защищена от доступа других приложений (Using the Internal Storage).
**Внешняя** (**external**) память — это общее «внешнее хранилище», т.е. это может быть как часть встроенной памяти, так и удаляемое устройство. Обычно это часть встроенной памяти, как удаляемое устройство я видел в последний раз на андройде 2.2, где встроенная память была около 2Гб, и подключаемая память становилась внешней (Using the External Storage).
**Удаляемая** (**removable**) память — все хранилища, которые могут быть удалены из устройства без «хирургических» вмешательств.

Я писал приложения и когда хотел,что-то записать на флешку получал путь `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` . И тестировал на эмуляторе или смартфоне без внешней SD карты. И казалось всё работает. Но сегодня я понял, что если использовать смартфон, куда можно подключить  SD карту, метод `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` вернет путь не к флешке, а к внешней памяти.
На форуме увидел такой ответ: Что производитель сам решает, что считать Внешней памятью и понятие SD карта в андроид отсутствует. И что  надо обратиться к производителю за способом получения доступа к флешке. Так же предлагают различные "костыли" для поиска внешних подключенных устройств, которые работают на большинстве, но всё же не всем существующем многообразии устройств. 
Собственно вот куча способов предложенных для поиска пути к SD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933
Но этот вопрос был задан 6 лет назад и даже тогда в выбранном правильном ответе говорится, что в андроид 4.4 произошли изменения. Но тем не менее пишут о том, что писать можно в каталоги, которые принадлежат приложению, типа`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app_name/`.

**А как же мне писать в другие каталоги, которые не принадлежат моему приложению? как получить например корневую папку SD и записать в него, что-то ? Появились ли в апи подобные интерфейсы?**
 У меня смартфон с 32 гб встроенной памяти, но еще есть возможность вместо одной симкарты подключить еще и SD карту и я не знаю как в этом случае поведут себя приложения. Думаю они  все по прежнему будут работать  с external памятью. 
И под конец вопроса приходит в голову мысль о том, что стандартом является использовать либо external и считать его внешней, либо флешку(removable) и устройств с и тем и другим не так то и много и для них до сих пор приходится использовать извращенные методы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663369/213148 уже неоднократно отвечаю на этот вопрос здесь...

Comment: этот ответ один из вариантов и на Marshmallow бесполезен

Comment: Видать ситуация такая же как и была раньше. И лучше вообще не пытаться делать программу, которая будет хранить что то на removable, если есть внешняя память.

Comment: странно - почему-то у меня и пользователей моей программы 4-7 андроид все работает...

Comment: наверняка ваша программа сперва проверяет наличие removable памяти, её в основном у пользователей нет и работа идет с внешней памятью.

Comment: да, именно проверка наличия флешки либо другой подключенной памяти (не внутренней).